# ngModel checks my checkboxes?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I'm using a form with hundreds of checkboxes for my shop search engine. Everything works smoothly, except that `ngModel` seems that checks all of my checkboxes. Why is that? I don't see `checked` anywhere in the `Elements` tab in my browser...

HTML:

```
<form #filterForm="ngForm" *ngIf="properties">
    <fieldset ngModelGroup="inputs" #inputs="ngModelGroup">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;" (click)="toggleTab('filters')">Филтриране на резултатите</button>
        <div id="filters" style="display: none;">
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let property of properties.SearchPropertyInfoList.Content.Item">
                    <h5>{{property.Name}}</h5>
                    <div class="filter">
                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let value of property.Values.PropertyValue">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="{{property.Id + '-' + value.Id}}" 
                                [ngModel]="property.Id + '-' + value.Id" class="custom-control-input" />
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description">{{value.Name}}</span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;" (click)="searchBy(filterForm)">Запази филтрите</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
searchBy(filterForm) {
    console.log(filterForm.form.value.inputs);
}
```

---

EDIT:

Also, how can I join the values of the inputs as a comma-separated string? They should become: `1627207-3232483,1627207-3232484...`. I've tried with `filterForm.form.value.inputs.join()`, but it gives `join is not a function` error.

> {"1627207-3232483":"1627207-3232483","1627207-3232484":"1627207-3232484","1627207-3232481":"1627207-3232481"}

Comment: Use `[checked]` to have more control over your checkbox

Comment: I will, but still.. when I added `[checked]` with some conditions - they were checked again...

Comment: You can use `ngModel` but it should be bound to a boolean value. If you bind it to a non-empty string, it will always be "truthy" and the checkbox will be checked.

Comment: Indeed, using `[ngModel]=""` works. Now I have to figure out how to join with `,` all input keys, if the value is `true`...

Comment: can you use `[ngModel]="property.Id == value.Id"` ?

Comment: Nope, they're different... `property.Id` is the category of the filter (ex. Size), and `value.Id` is the property of the category (ex. XL).

Comment: Anyway, using `[ngModel]=""` and making the function to: `searchBy(filterForm) { let result = ''; Object.entries(filterForm.form.value.inputs).forEach(([key, value]) => { if(value == true) { result += key + ','; } }); result = result.slice(0, -1); console.log(result); }` seems to work. I think it's kind of ugly, but that the best I can do... Thanks guys!

Comment: putting `[ngModel]=""` inside the checkbox is not a good practice because usually ngModel is used as [(ngModel)] for two way data binding. to update the modal and the view and sync them. if the expression is empty, ngModel will loose its meaning and intent.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the only way to get all checked checkboxes (dynamically created with ngFor) that I know...